# Why dont my elements line up right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website for my company but I have run into a problem with the positioning of the logo and p elements. I would like them to display on the same line but it isn't quite working how I wanted it to. 
Here is my HTML:

```
    <header class="mainHeader">
        <div class="imageholder"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" title="Detect Fire and Security Worthing Logo"/></a></div>
        <div class="textholder"><h2 class="number" style="color: #FFF"><p>admin@detect-fs.co.uk</p><p>01903 659 245</p></h2></div>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="intruder_alarms.html">Intruder Alarms</a></li>
                <li><a href="cctv.html">CCTV</a></li>
                <li><a href="fire_alarms.html">Fire Alarms</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

and my CSS:

```
.imageholder {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
}

.textholder {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
    width: 50%;
    line-height: 20%;
    position: relative;
}

.mainHeader img {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2% 0 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
```

I thought that if the two divs, imageholder and textholder, were a 50% width it would work but what then happens is the height of the logo is then 50% which I don't want but I can't seem to increase the height after that.

Comment: width does not work on inline elements and you cannot nest paragraphs inside headings.

Comment: For adding "ASAP" to your question, and then not responding to any answer, a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.textholder *{ 
    display: inline;
}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/fj1hn19c/

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the height of the image is scaling with its aspect ratio so when the width is increasing, so is the height.

To solve this you could use the `max-height` CSS style but depending on the aspect ratio of the image, it could stretch and pixelate it. You could also set a `max-width` for the image to prevent it from stretching beyond what you would like.

Also, if you want those elements to align like block-level elements then I'd suggest using `display: inline-block` as opposed to `display: inline`

An image of the misalignment would further help us see the problem the same way you do.

Answer (score 0):

Noah, it is difficult to answer this without more information e.g. I can't see what container element "mainheader" sits inside and what it's CSS is and what your paragraph tag css is?

There are a couple of things I can suggest based on the information you have provided though:

One is to code your textholder.p CSS to have zero margins:

```
margin-top: 0; 
margin-bottom:0;
```

browsers automatically add an empty line before and after a paragraph which could be part of the issue.

Second is to check the padding, margin, in-line and float settings in your CSS for whatever the parent/container element of "mainheader".